# Build target skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ConditionNameHere)' - unsure how to change

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build-process

Initial Disclaimer: I have limited experience with C++ in Visual Studio so be nice :)

I'm trying to use a Windows port of Flex/Bison in my project (VS2013), but after following the instructors to add the build customisation (http://sourceforge.net/p/winflexbison/wiki/Visual%20Studio%20custom%20build%20rules/), it's failing a condition and not executing:

```
   Target "BisonTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(Bison)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
   Target "FlexTarget" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(Flex)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
```

Obviously this is just failing based on some build/environment variable, however after a long time Googling I can't actually figure out where the @(NameHere) variables are set so I can force the build.

Can anyone advise where/how I would change these variables to enable the execution of the new build files?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure flex.exe and bison.exe are in your PATH (add them to %PATH%). I have in mine `PATH=%PATH%;C:\Cola\GnuWin32\bin`
   (Once you fix the PATH you need to restart Visual Studio)
2. Make sure the `GNU Tools.targets` or (whatever the filename) is listed in the custom build rules. In Visual Studio this is a global setting, so you only need it once for all of your parser projects. If not, right click on the project and choose Build Customization, then click Find Existing... and browse to your .targets file.
3. Right click your Bison and Flex source files (.y/.ypp or .l) and select from `Item Type` the appropriate file type, it should correlate to the targets you just added. There should be values like Flex and Bison in the drop-down list for `Item Type`.

Regarding `('@(Flex)' != '')`

As far as I know this is an MSBuild condition, and it is evaluating the variable for empty. If it is non-empty, the Condition is true and will execute the Target.

As an example, for context, my .targets file has:

```
  <Target
    Name="_Bison"
    BeforeTargets="$(BisonBeforeTargets)"
    AfterTargets="$(BisonAfterTargets)"
    Condition="'@(Bison)' != ''"
```

Comment: Thanks Melvin, but the version I'm using has win-bison.exe and win-flex.exe and doesn't have any .rule files. I manually added the path to the exes in my OS %PATH% but I'm still getting the same error.
According to the build instructions linked above, all I have to do is include the .targets file, which I have. The only other files are a .props and .xml with the same name as the .targets file. 

Can you advise what the @(Flex) actually is (i.e. is it actually a variable?) and if it has a proper name that I might be able to Google to find how to change it?

Comment: @walshy002000 Oops, I meant .targets, not .rules.

Comment: Yep, got that. The condition it's failing is what' defined in the .targets, so I know that VS is processing it correctly, I'm just not sure why it's failing with the @(Flex) != '' condition.

Comment: @walshy002000 - Look at my last edit. Check and see if you set the item type for your Bison or Flex source file. I have to set mine to Bison++ and Flex. They aren't set by default. Maybe its just the way I've always done it, but I assumed this was the correct way.

Comment: Thanks Melvin, but I don't seem to have Flex/Bison++ as a file type option in the dropdown which is odd.

Any idea where I can set the @(Flex) variable for MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, I removed and re-added the .y and .l files and everything worked. Quite odd, but something to note if you're having the same problem.

Was suggested by the library devs over at https://sourceforge.net/p/winflexbison/discussion/general/thread/18a9d465/?limit=50